# Attempt to read from field 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

DataBindingUtil.inflate return null always, and error was

> Attempt to read from field 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView com.hkapps.wallpaperbase.databinding.FragmentFavouriteBinding.recyclerView' on a null object reference

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreateView(layoutInflater,viewGroup, bundle);
    this.binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater,
            R.layout.fragment_favourite,
            viewGroup,
            true);
    initObjects();
    initRecyclerView();
    return this.binding.getRoot();
}
```

[image: you can see picture of debug mode in android studio]

Comment: did you initialize the ReciclerView?

Comment: actually DataBindingUtil return null on inflate or setContentView any of the method

Comment: initRecyclerView(); it will initialize recyclerview

Comment: Your question is not enough , try posting Logcat or initRecyclerView() code , to get relevant answers.
Have u initialized recyclerview from parent view ?

Comment: private void initRecyclerView() {
        this.binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        this.adapter = new FavouriteFragmentAdapter(getContext(), this, this.mList);
        this.binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    }

Comment: can you edit your question and add your layout, initObjects and initRecyclerView methods?